# add_custom_command POST_BUILD to run shell script after 3 targets are built?

Tags: cmake

I have 3 targets in cmake added by add_executable()

I want to run a shell script after these 3 targets are done / built.

Usually, I do this for one target:

```
 add_custom_command(TARGET TARGET1 POST_BUILD
               VERBATIM
               COMMAND SHELL_SCRIPT CALL HERE
              )
```

But, how about if I want to run the script after 3 targets are built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the following will ensure the script is always executed only after the three executables are build:

```
add_executable(prog1 main1.cc)
add_executable(prog2 main2.cc)
add_executable(prog3 main3.cc)

add_custom_target(
  ExecuteScript ALL
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Executed after targets are built"
  VERBATIM
  )

add_dependencies(ExecuteScript prog1 prog2 prog3)
```